# Flexbox media query overflowing divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I got a problem that I need to solve. I am coding an admin panel. I am using flexbox and I have 3 divs next to each other. Code looks like this:

```
<div class="content-boxes">
    <div class="content-box">
      <span>Something</span>
      <img src="image.png">
      <p>
        Number<br>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="content-box">
      <span>Something</span>
      <img src="image.png">
      <p>
        Number<br>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="content-box">
      <span>Something</span>
      <img src="image.png">
      <p>
        Number<br>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And CSS code **(SASS)**:

```
.content-boxes{
  position: relative;
  @include flexbox();
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 18%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 1vw 1vw 1vw 1vw;
  .content-box{
    @include flexbox();
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width:23%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: $oc-red-8;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex: 1;
    span{
      padding: 0.2vw;
      font-size: 3vh;
      color: $oc-gray-2;
      overflow: hidden;
      font-family: CaviarDreams;
      width: 100%;
    }
    p{
      padding: 1vw;
      font-size: 4vh;
      color: $oc-gray-2;
      overflow: hidden;
      font-family: CaviarDreams;
      text-align: right;
      align-self: center;
      margin-left: auto;
    }
    img{
      height: 50%;
      align-self: flex-start;
      margin-left: 1vw;
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is that when I use media query and wants the boxes to be width: 100%; the other divs as flex are overflowing this one.

Media query code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 650px){
  .content-boxes{
    .content-box{
       width: 100%;
    }
  }
}
```

I wants all my divs under each other with width: 100%;

I hope I made myself clear, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to change the direction of the flex and make it column instead of row :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 650px){
  .content-boxes{
    flex-direction:column;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution will be like that

you define `flex: 1`

for the content box which is mean :

```
flex-grow: 1;
flex-shrink: 1;
flex-basis: 0%;
```

and you want the width 100% in the media query then you have to define this

```
flex-grow: 1;
flex-shrink: 1;
flex-basis: auto;
```

which is shortcut `flex: auto` as you define already `width 100%`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 650px){
  .content-boxes{
    .content-box{
      flex: auto;
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
}
```

so it will be under each other

and here the codepen [link](http://codepen.io/AElkhodary/pen/EbzzMq)